# What does "Advance a Move" mean in Urban Shadows 2nd edition?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, urban-shadows-2e

I know the final book is still being written and the Quickstart Rules may change before publication, but the game is already easily playable, despite this advancement rule that is common is several playbooks:

In various playbooks, under Advancement:

> advance 3 basic moves

The Fae, under End Move:

> ... or advance persuade an NPC

But the quickstart never says what is *Advancing a move* or how it works. Even making it look like an incorrect or imcomplete rule.

Is it to get a bonus when rolling for that move? Or a +1 to its related Stat? Where do we write which move is advanced on the playbook?

Comment: You were unlucky enough to catch the one issue of the Quick Start that didn't define the Advanced moves. Download the latest version (v.7) and you'll see them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In many Powered by the Apocalypse (PbtA) games, you can advance basic moves such that they offer an additional benefit on a roll of 12 or higher. *Urban Shadows* continues that trend.

For example: On a 10+ roll when you "Turn to Violence," you inflict harm as established AND can choose to "inflict terrible harm," "take something from them," or "create an opportunity for an ally." Normally, if you roll a 12+ that's no different than rolling a 10 or 11, but if the move has been advanced you can instead choose two of the options above, instead of one.

In the most recent version of the Quickstart (v7, released May 26th), the advanced clauses of the Basic Moves are listed in their own section on page 29, after the other Basic Move summaries. You'd reference those for any moves a character has advanced through... advancement.

Comment: That's a great answer!

Comment: I just found another small issue. The Aware move _The Lion's Den_ says it works as rolled 12+, but Circle moves are not advanced.